# wrong grub prefix (efi) `grub-install` and `update-grub` doesn't fix it

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, pop-os

**problem:**

When booting, grub goes to the prompt (`grub>`, not `grub rescue>`).
I need to type in:

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt8)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

To get the normal grub menu.

Every post I found so far was solved by doing `grub-install` and/or `update-grub` once you manage to boot your system. 
I tried these but the problem persists.

**details:**

I dual boot with windows 10 and pop-os (ubuntu-based).
I have an acer laptop with boot mode set to `UEFI` and secure boot `enabled`.

My partitions look like this:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID,LABEL,PARTUUID,PARTTYPE
NAME            SIZE FSTYPE MOUNTPOINT UUID                                 LABEL    PARTUUID                             PARTTYPE
sda           238.5G                                                                                                      
├─sda1          529M ntfs              6272EE1672EDEF2B                     Recovery b593e2b8-992e-4d79-9074-d990ba21d10c de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
├─sda2          100M vfat              64EE-A907                                     6ef6e12c-3858-4a83-a1dd-8297719bd477 c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b
├─sda3           16M                                                                 1b6ba39a-e528-4cf9-b158-cd1a9312afc2 e3c9e316-0b5c-4db8-817d-f92df00215ae
├─sda4        117.2G ntfs              8E6008B56008A655                              c2f2d5bf-16a3-4e99-a6db-2385b36f3f46 ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
├─sda5         58.6G ntfs              F6D0CCD7D0CC9EED                     Storage  c10e8d39-26c3-4d3b-8548-0aa97816ba0b ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
├─sda6          477M swap              74da5edc-3b6c-4644-a151-6b93562c8fa4          408e91bd-c7e7-4ab8-a2ac-bb2bb7fde375 0657fd6d-a4ab-43c4-84e5-0933c84b4f4f
│ └─cryptswap 476.5M swap   [SWAP]     2d2336c7-64c1-4d53-8e99-f66f9b93bef5                                               
├─sda7          600M vfat   /boot/efi  7565-8082                                     a8c1ff00-3790-4ca0-a360-642e6f1859f0 c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b
└─sda8           61G ext4   /          d40fe3bd-0749-4c29-9e9b-97a064a659dd          8a3b8567-c511-48cd-a3fa-776b556d17da 0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4
```

- Partitions 1-4 were created by windows, the bootloader is on `sda2`.
- Partition 5 is created by me to easily share files between windows/linux.
- The remaining partitions were created by pop-os (after completing the windows installation),
  the pop-os bootloader is on `sda7`.

I installed grub as:

```
$ sudo apt install grub-efi
$ sudo grub-install --bootloader-id=grub
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-7642-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-7642-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-7634-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-7634-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-7629-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-7629-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-7626-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-7626-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

After which my `/boot` directory looks like this:

```
$ sudo tree -a /boot
/boot
├── config-5.4.0-7626-generic
├── config-5.4.0-7629-generic
├── config-5.4.0-7634-generic
├── config-5.4.0-7642-generic
├── efi
│   ├── c0cc91f7cdfcb9a597d9db525eb08842
│   ├── EFI
│   │   ├── BOOT
│   │   │   └── BOOTX64.EFI
│   │   ├── Linux
│   │   ├── grub
│   │   │   ├── grub.cfg
│   │   │   └── grubx64.efi
│   │   ├── Pop_OS-d40fe3bd-0749-4c29-9e9b-97a064a659dd
│   │   │   ├── cmdline
│   │   │   ├── initrd.img
│   │   │   ├── initrd.img-previous
│   │   │   ├── vmlinuz.efi
│   │   │   └── vmlinuz-previous.efi
│   │   └── systemd
│   │       └── systemd-bootx64.efi
│   ├── loader
│   │   ├── entries
│   │   │   ├── Pop_OS-current.conf
│   │   │   └── Pop_OS-oldkern.conf
│   │   ├── loader.conf
│   │   └── random-seed
│   └── System Volume Information
│       ├── AadRecoveryPasswordDelete
│       └── ClientRecoveryPasswordRotation
├── grub
│   ├── fonts
│   │   └── unicode.pf2
│   ├── grub.cfg
│   ├── grubenv
│   └── x86_64-efi
│       ├── acpi.mod
|       < files omitted ... > 
│       └── zstd.mod
├── initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.4.0-7642-generic
├── initrd.img-5.3.0-7642-generic
< files omitted ... > 
├── initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.4.0-7634-generic
├── System.map-5.4.0-7626-generic
< files omitted ... > 
├── vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-7642-generic
├── vmlinuz-5.4.0-7626-generic
< files omitted ... > 
└── vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-7634-generic

16 directories, 314 files
```

The files under `/boot/efi/EFI/grub`, `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT` and `/boot/grub` are newly added by `grub-install`.

In addition, this looks fine to me:

```
$ cat /boot/efi/EFI/grub/grub.cfg 
search.fs_uuid d40fe3bd-0749-4c29-9e9b-97a064a659dd root hd0,gpt8 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

After rebooting, i hit F2 and managed to add `EFI/grub/grubx64` to the top of the boot order.
[image]

After saving & exiting I land into the grub prompt.

Then, using the `set` command I see the following output (some entries omitted):

```
grub> set
cmdpath=(hd0,gpt7)/EFI/grub
grub_cpu=x86_64
grub_platform=efi
prefix=(hd0,gpt7)/EFI/ubuntu
root=(hd0,gpt7)
```

I'm lost now, it seems that the correct bootloader was loaded (`cmdpath=(hd0,gpt7)/EFI/pop`),
but the settings in `EFI/grub/grub.cfg` are completely ignored.
Where is it getting these incorrect settings from?

After fixing `prefix` as decribed above, I get a fully functional grub menu with an entry for 1. pop-os, 2. pop-os fallback images, 3. windows and 4. the boot setup. I tried all options and they all work.

So I managed to boot into popOs, `efibootmgr -v` tells me this:

```
$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0001,0002,0000,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager     HD(2,GPT,6ef6e12c-3858-4a83-a1dd-8297719bd477,0x109000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0001* systemd                  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17,0x0)/Sata(2,0,0)/HD(7,GPT,a8c1ff00-3790-4ca0-a360-642e6f1859f0,0x160d3000,0x12c000)/File(\EFI\systemd\systemd-bootx64.efi)A01 ..
Boot0002* HDD0: HFS256G39TND-N210A PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17,0x0)/Sata(2,0,0)/HD(7,GPT,a8c1ff00-3790-4ca0-a360-642e6f1859f0,0x160d3000,0x12c000)RC
Boot0003* grub                     PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17,0x0)/Sata(2,0,0)/HD(7,GPT,a8c1ff00-3790-4ca0-a360-642e6f1859f0,0x160d3000,0x12c000)/File(\EFI\grub\grubx64.efi)A01 ..
Boot0004* EFI USB Device           RC
Boot0005* EFI DVD/CDROM            RC
Boot0006* EFI Network              RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device           RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM            RC
Boot2003* EFI Network              RC
```

**what I expect should happen**

1. I start grub, at `(hd0,gpt7)/EFI/grub/grub.efi` from the UEFI firmware.
2. grub reads the config file at `(hd0,gpt7)/EFI/grub/grub.cfg`.
   This sets `root` to `(hd0,gpt8)`
   and `prefix` to `(hd0,gpt8)/boot/grub`.
3. grub loads the configuration at `(hd0,gpt8)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.
4. grub presents me with a menu, I choose the OS I want to load and go on with my day.

**what actually happens**

1. I start grub, at `(hd0,gpt7)/EFI/grub/grub.efi` from the UEFI firmware.
2. grub **does not** read the config file at
   `(hd0,gpt7)/EFI/grub/grub.cfg`.
   Instead it sets `root` to `(hd0,gpt7)`
   and `prefix` to `(hd0,gpt7)/boot/ubuntu`. 
   I manually fix the incorrect `prefix` as described above.
3. grub loads the configuration at `(hd0,gpt8)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.
4. grub presents me with a menu, I choose the OS I want to load and go on with my day.

**things I tried:**

- disabling secure boot (no difference)
- re-running `grub-install` and `upgrade-grub` (no difference)
- `sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=grub --recheck --debug /dev/sda &> grub.log` (no difference, [output here](https://gist.github.com/SamDM/bd93f23fcfad6439f79d7dc75db478f2))

Comment: You show two vfat partitions, are both set as ESP. Generally you can only have one as ESP, but entries for grub and maybe UEFI use UUIDs & GUIDS, so flag is more for where boot loader is installed. And then do you have an old UEFI grub entry in Windows's ESP that is failing to boot?  Check that GUID/partUUID in UEFI boot entry matches partuuid. `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid | egrep -v "^loop"` and `sudo efibootmgr -v`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I don't really know what you mean by 'are both set at ESP', how should I check this? I Also put the output of the commands you gave in a gist (https://gist.github.com/SamDM/bd93f23fcfad6439f79d7dc75db478f2#file-feedback-oldfred). If I interpret the output correctly, the entries seem to match.

Comment: Also, on `dev/sda` I can't see any grub-related files. I believe all files on that partition are created by windows (file tree: https://gist.github.com/SamDM/bd93f23fcfad6439f79d7dc75db478f2#file-sda2).

Comment: If you look close your "ubuntu" entry at 0007 uses GUID from sda2. Pop entry which shows as default uses sda7. With most Acer, you have to set "trust" on entry to have it work. Is Pop entry "trusted"? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947 Many Acer also need UEFI update. https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217061/installation-on-acer-swift-5-freezes-no-partitions-shown

Comment: Yep I am a bit puzzled by the `Boot0007`, which points to a non existing file on the filesystem. It may be a remnant of an old ubuntu install. And maybe I should try removing it. Although I doubt it would solve anything, it is worth trying. To answer your question, I have indeed added the `EFI/pop/grubx64.efi` entry to the trusted bootloaders in the Acer firmware settings. This is the file generated by `grub-install`. I'm pretty confident this `pop` entry is also the one that is booted up since `cmdpath=(hd0,gpt7)/EFI/pop` in the grub shell.

Comment: Also grub is for boot without UEFI Secure Boot on. You have to use shim for Secure boot.  But I do not think you would have been able to manually boot if Secure Boot was on. You can remove UEFI boot entries with efibootmgr and its -b XXXX -B parameters. See `man efibootmgr`

Comment: Hi, thx for the input. I cleaned up a little and removed old entries. As for the secure boot, it certainly does look like it's on (see the newly attached screenshot in the answer) and I'm still able to boot (by setting the prefix, insmod, etc) into a working grub menu. Further, nothing has changed.

Comment: Not familiar with PciRoot type command to know if parameters are all correct. Is your system using shell to create entries, not efibootmgr? Your Windows entry is typical for an Ubuntu entry booting grub or shim that is created by efibootmgr.

Comment: The `efibootmgr` output seems fine to me. I can boot all of these options without any issue from the UEFI firmware settings. I don't think the problem lies there. The problem seems to be contained to grub itself: it is ignoring the configuration file located at: `EFI/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: I use Ubuntu and it has grub.cfg in ESP. But it looks like POP!OS uses loader.conf http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man7/systemd-boot.7.html & http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man5/loader.conf.5.html

Comment: I also have a `grub.cfg` in ESP, see the file tree I put in the post. The `loader.conf` file is indeed for `systemd-boot` (aka gummiboot), not for grub. This is what the `systemd` entry of `efibootmgr -v` does. However, I don't think the problem lies there. When I start up the grub boot loader (first entry in the screenshot) all of the `systemd-boot` and `loader.conf` stuff is irrelevant. The cause of the issue is that grub loads up as a command prompt instead of a menu because it doesn't realize that my root partition is gpt8, not gpt7. I need some way to tell it to use the correct `prefix`.

Comment: I do not understand, everything you posted above in question is gpt7, not gpt8? Does /EFI/grub/grub.cfg refer to gpt7 or gpt8? And then were is full grub.cfg gpt7 or gpt8?

Comment: Well, gpt7 is the ESP, gpt8 is the PopOs root partition. `EFI/grub/grub.cfg` is a minimal config file that only sets the `root` and `prefix`, it is located on gpt7, which is, after the system is fully booted up, mounted at `/boot/efi`. The contents of `EFI/grub/grub.cfg` correctly indicate that the larger grub configuration file resides on gtp8 (at`/grub/grub.cfg` to be precise).

Comment: I added some clarification to my post, see the points _what I expect should happen_ and _what actually happens_ in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact reason for this problem is not yet entirely clear, but it may have something to do with incorrectly configured grub packages by the popOs maintainers.

I managed to work around it by copying the grub files created by `grub-install` to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`. If you're on popOs and did `grub-install` without any options, then the following should work:

```
sudo mv /boot/efi/EFI/pop /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu
```

An alternative workaround, which I haven't tested is:

```
sudo cp /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi /boot/efi/EFI/pop/grubx64.efi
```

For more info, see the [bug report](https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/1007).

Answer (score 2):

When `grubx64.efi` is generated by `grub-mkimage`, a default `prefix` value can be embedded into it.

In Debian, this is set to `/EFI/debian` when `grub-mkimage` is called by `grub-install`; in Ubuntu, the prefix will be `/EFI/ubuntu` respectively. This causes GRUB to first read a mini-configuration file located as `/EFI/(debian|ubuntu)/grub.cfg`, which typically contains only a few lines to redirect GRUB into wherever the `/boot` directory/filesystem is located, to read the real configuration file from there:

```
<any configuration lines required to cover complications like software RAID, disk encryption or LVM>
search.fs_uuid <UUID of the filesystem that contains /boot>
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub' # or just ($root)/grub if /boot is a separate filesystem 
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

If you are using Pop!OS's GRUB package, it might have a similar left-over "ubuntuism" in its `grub-install`/`grub-mkimage` defaults, if Pop's packagers have not paid enough attention. And since Pop's default UEFI bootloader seems to be gummiboot rather than GRUB, such a bug might have gone unnoticed.

If you have installed the `grub-efi-amd64-signed` package for Secure Boot compatibility, your original `/boot/efi/EFI/pop/grubx64.efi` may in fact be different from `/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi`, as the former has gone through the Secure Boot signing process and usually has essentially all the GRUB modules built-in.

Perhaps the Pop!OS developers have used Ubuntu's `grub-efi-amd64-signed` package as-is, without applying the changes they've made to the non-SecureBoot-signed version?

---

Background:

When `grub-install` is used with the `--uefi-secure-boot` option, or if Secure Boot is detected, then instead of using `grub-mkimage` to build an optimized `grubx64.efi` for the system GRUB is being installed to, it uses a pre-compiled and Secure Boot-signed `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signed/grubx64.efi.signed`.

At least in Debian, this is built using reproducible build techniques, so with the corresponding version of the source package and a detached Secure Boot signature file, anyone can compile it for themselves and verify that the result will be absolutely identical to the pre-built version. Getting *that* part working right was apparently the major reason why it took a while to get Secure Boot support into Debian.

Comment: Hi, your answer led me to a solution! You're right that searching for `EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` is hard-baked into the binary. So here is what I did: `sudo mv /boot/efi/EFI/grub /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`. Then I did a reboot and I land right into a fully functional grub menu with options for popOs (on gpt7 & 8) windows (on gpt 2 and 4) and UEFI firmware settings. It all works perfectly. It does look like a an oversight from popOs developers. Because by default `grub-install` will put the (small) config file in `/boot/efi/EFI/pop`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, If you could include my workaround in your answer I'll accept it as 'solved'. If you don't care about SO reputation I'll post my own answer describing the workaround.

Comment: Now that I know what to look for, I also found the following workaround (haven't tested it myself): `sudo cp /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi /boot/efi/EFI/pop/grubx64.efi`. See https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/1007

Comment: @SamDeMeyer Feel free to post your own answer. If copying `/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi` to `/boot/efi/EFI/pop/grubx64.efi` helps, it might be that the actual GRUB package of Pop!OS is now fixed, but the fix may have not been propagated to the `grub-efi-amd64-signed` package (which provides another copy of `grubx64.efi` that's been signed for Secure Boot).

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [Sam De Meyer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/616659/498611) Answer,

> An alternative workaround, which I haven't tested is:
>
> ```bash
> sudo cp /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi /boot/efi/EFI/pop/grubx64.efi
> ```

Moving `grub.efi` from `/boot/grub/x86_64-efi` to the efi partition (which one on my os is on `/boot/efi/EFI/neon/grubx64.efi`) makes the GRUB's theme could not be used even though I have applied it in `/etc/default/grub` with `GRUB_THEME` configuration. The default blue grub theme is used instead.

The solution for me to fix [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615109/wrong-grub-prefix-efi-grub-install-and-update-grub-doesnt-fix-it) issue with keeping my theme works is just to copy the `/boot/efi/EFI/neon/grub.cfg` to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`

```bash
sudo cp /boot/efi/EFI/neon/grub.cfg /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
```

Before doing that, you should run `sudo grub-install` first.